# Compare value member when setting property

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, comparison

I have a property, of a custom class, in C# that I have overridden the setter for. I want to compare a property of/in the custom class in the setter, like the following:

```
public DatabaseInfo CurrentDatabaseManagedSelection 
{
   get { return CurrentDatabaseManaged; }
   set {
         if (String.Equals(value.Name,  CurrentDatabaseManaged.Name,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))    
              return;  
         CurrentDatabaseManaged = DatabaseManagement.ReadDatabase(value.FileName);
       }
}
```

Inside the DatabaseInfo class, there is a standard String property called Name.

However, when I run the program I get the following exception. Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to solve the issue please?

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

EDIT: I do set the value of the property which the setter above is for, in the constructor of the view model. I do this simply by setting `CurrentDatabaseManagedSelection` equal to an object of the DatabaseInfo class.

Comment: We - _at least me_ - might need more information. The following would work without problem `set { if (string.Equals(value, Name)) return; _name = value;}` in a basic class structure. Is it possible to give complete definition for the property so that we can see how it's defined ? Also how do you set it in constructor ?

Comment: @MechnicalObject Ok, I will update the question to add more information in a minute :)

Comment: @Andy tell me the inner exception. It has to be related with null reference

Comment: @Andy but i wonder why == didn't solve your problem

Comment: @EhsanUllah I'm not sure. The exception message said `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`... Does that give any clues? It was the `CurrentDatabaseManaged` at fault.

Comment: @Andy i had the hunch about the inner exception already. That is why i posted that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I might have found the problem... *Well*, I've solved it!

The issue was `CurrentDatabaseManaged` had not been initialized and so was equal to `null` when I tried setting the above property. I discovered this by adding a try.. catch in the setter method, and created a new String for `CurrentDatabaseManaged.Name` - the stack trace pointed to that line.

Hope that helps some one else in the future.

Comment: Nice to hear that you found the problem. You might also want to add a guard close _if not already done_ in `ReadDatabase(value.FileName);` method to determine how your method will react when you pass a null or empty string.

Comment: @MechanicalObject Yes, I have already done this but thank you for the advicel